# How to populate a ListBox based on a list of a model in asp.net mvc4?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, html.listboxfor

I have a strongly typed view where I have a form based on a Model Contact. In the textboxes, the default values are those of the contact that I'm passing to the view in the controller.
So I have a class **Contact** as follows:

```
public class Contact
    {
        public int IdContact { get; set; }
        public string Nom { get; set; }
        public string Prenom { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Fonction { get; set; }
        public List<FonctionContact> ListeFonctions = new List<FonctionContact>();
        public string TelephoneFixe { get; set; }
        public string TelephonePort { get; set; }
        public Contact() { }

        public Contact(int idContact, string nom, string prenom, string email, string telephoneFixe, string telephonePort)
        {
            this.IdContact = idContact;
            this.Nom = nom;
            this.Prenom = prenom;
            this.Email = email;
            this.TelephoneFixe = telephoneFixe;
            this.TelephonePort = telephonePort;
        }

        public Contact(int idContact, string nom, string prenom, List<FonctionContact> listeFonctions, string email, string telephoneFixe, string telephonePort)
        {
            this.IdContact = idContact;
            this.Nom = nom;
            this.Prenom = prenom;
            this.ListeFonctions = listeFonctions;
            this.Email = email;
            this.TelephoneFixe = telephoneFixe;
            this.TelephonePort = telephonePort;
        }
    }
```

There is a list of **FonctionContact**. The class of FonctionContact:

```
public class FonctionContact
{
    public int IdFonction;
    public string LibelleFonction;

    public FonctionContact() { }

    public FonctionContact(int idFonction, string libelleFonction)
    {
        this.IdFonction = idFonction;
        this.LibelleFonction = libelleFonction;
    }
}
```

So I would like to display the property **ListeFonctions** of the Contact in a listBoxfor but it doesn't work. There is my form where I've tried to display the list :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){ 
     <label>Nom:</label>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(contact => contact.Nom, new { @Value = @Model.Nom })
     <label>Prénom:</label>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(contact => contact.Prenom, new { @Value = @Model.Prenom })
     ///the next controls for the next properties of class Contact...
     <label>Fonction(s):</label>
     @Html.ListBoxFor(contact => contact.ListeFonctions, new SelectList(Model.ListeFonctions, "IdFonction", "LibelleFonction"));
     }
```

It shows me an error: "Model.FonctionContact doesn't have a property IdFonction. So I'm stuck here, I can't find out what's wrong. Somebody has an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you'll need to provide the ListBoxFor with a list of value items (integers, which you could use to load some previously selected and saved items). Also, it will need a MultiSelectList as the second parameter (for the previously explained reason, because it's not a DropDownList with just one selected item), which would probably be neater to compose in the model, as I have written below:

**Model**

```
public class Contact
        {
            public int IdContact { get; set; }
            public string Nom { get; set; }
            public string Prenom { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Fonction { get; set; }

            // you could save a selection of items from that list
            private List<int> _selectedFonctionIds;        
            public List<int> SelectedFonctionIds{
                get {
                    return _selectedFonctionIds?? new List<int>();
                }
                set {
                    _selectedFonctionIds= value;
                }
            }
            private List<FonctionContact> _listeFonctions;
            public MultiSelectList ListeFonctions{
               get {
                  return new MultiSelectList(
                            _listeFonctions,
                            "IdFonction", // dataValueField
                            "LibelleFonction" // dataTextField
                  );
                   }
            }
            public string TelephoneFixe { get; set; }
            public string TelephonePort { get; set; }
            public Contact() { }

            public Contact(int idContact, string nom, string prenom, string email, string telephoneFixe, string telephonePort)
            {
                this.IdContact = idContact;
                this.Nom = nom;
                this.Prenom = prenom;
                this.Email = email;
                this.TelephoneFixe = telephoneFixe;
                this.TelephonePort = telephonePort;
            }

            public Contact(int idContact, string nom, string prenom, List<int> selectedFonctionIds, List<FonctionContact> listeFonctions, string email, string telephoneFixe, string telephonePort)
            {
                this.IdContact = idContact;
                this.Nom = nom;
                this.Prenom = prenom;
                this.SelectedFonctionIds = selectedFonctionIds;
                this._listeFonctions = listeFonctions;
                this.Email = email;
                this.TelephoneFixe = telephoneFixe;
                this.TelephonePort = telephonePort;
            }
        }
```

**inside the view's form**

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(contact => contact.SelectedFonctionIds, Model.ListeFonctions)
```

Comment: I've tried but it shows me a Databinding error saying that Class FonctionContact does not have such property as IdFonction

Comment: Have you tried actually making the IdFonction a property (`public int IdFonction { get; set; }` instead of just `public int IdFonction;`)? The same should probably be done for LibelleFonction also.

Comment: ... never work when u're tired ! it works !, thanks a lot @Mark